# What happened to the VB6 APIViewer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, vb6, vb6-migration

I am trying to get knowledge of some of the WinAPI's in vb.net, but can't find the tool that used to exist for vb6, API Viewer.

Does VS2015 happen to come with something easier?

Is there a similar way of importing WinAPI code from a tool into vb.net?

Comment: [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/)

Comment: It seems the Visual Studio add-in no longer exists. Is this the only way?

Comment: AFAIK yes, but it si pretty good for the well known API. Besides you should go to the WinAPI only for very specific cases. Usually the NET Libraries or some NuGet packages are all that is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that VS2015 does not include a tool for browsing the Win32 API.

I was able to find through the assistance of some helpful comments above, a website known as [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/). However, this is outdated.

I did find references to [PInvoke Interop Assistant](https://github.com/jaredpar/pinvoke-interop-assistant), which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Much of the Win32 API has managed wrappers, and thus it's not needed like it was in the days of VB6.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill - How do I figure out what the managed wrappers are?

Comment: I used Bing to search on keywords. That's how I found the FileSystemWatcher.